# My Ubuntu Freezes when I start it

Tags: 11.10

well when I start my ubuntu it looks like it works fine but I can't click any feature in the screen. I already tried it with two mouses and the arrow moves but I can't click anything in the screen. What should I do to make it work again?? I am new and I just installed Ubuntu in my PC. May you help me please?? I will be always grateful

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally get this and find it very annoying. The only way I've found to get round it is to fall back to a TTY terminal and restart the graphical server:

1. Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Log in
3. Run: `sudo restart lightdm`

That should take you back to the login screen (or desktop if you have automatic login) and for me, this fixes things, albeit until the next time it happens.

There is almost certainly an underlying bug in here and it's probably in Compiz (if you're using the standard "Ubuntu with effects" desktop). You might find that the Ubuntu 2D desktop (selectable from the login screen) works more reliably but your mileage may vary.